# Looking for a specific type of artificial intelligence

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I am looking to create a challenging AI project.

There is an online card game that allows you to build a deck to play with out of randomly presented cards. You have to choose one each time out of a couple of cards. I want to build an AI that picks the cards as I would pick them myself using my knowledge of the game.

My guess is that I would have to create a system that can be trained based on "experience" (taught by training) and adapts its choices based on which previous cards it has already selected.

I am looking for the specific name for this type of AI so I can start finding some resources for it or similar projects if you know any.

Comment: This was kinda opinion based question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the General term that you are looking for is *Reinforcement Learning*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning. A popular model free form of this is called Q Learning.

A recent example usage of this was to beat that incredibly difficult FlappyBird game: http://sarvagyavaish.github.io/FlappyBirdRL/

Comment: Thanks a lot for both the term and the very interesting practical example.